# CustomView couldn't be instantiated (error in editor preview and nothing shown after compile)

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

So, I created a `CustomView` called `ButtonWithCaption.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_normal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_normal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bwc_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bwc_caption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/bwc_icon"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Along with its controller `ButtonWithCaption.java`

```
public class ButtonWithCaption extends RelativeLayout {
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private TextView mTextView;
    private int mIconSrc;
    private String mCaptionText;
    private boolean mShowIcon;
    private boolean mShowText;

    public ButtonWithCaption(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public ButtonWithCaption(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ButtonWithCaption(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ButtonWithCaption, 0, 0);

        try {
            mIconSrc = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ButtonWithCaption_iconSrc, 0);
            mCaptionText = a.getString(R.styleable.ButtonWithCaption_captionText);
            mShowIcon = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ButtonWithCaption_showIcon, mIconSrc != 0);
            mShowText = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ButtonWithCaption_showText, !mCaptionText.isEmpty());

            mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bwc_icon);
            mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bwc_caption);

            mImageView.setImageResource(mIconSrc);
            mTextView.setText(mCaptionText);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy.

And then, I declare custom attributes in `attrs.xml`

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ButtonWithCaption">
        <attr name="iconSrc" format="reference" />
        <attr name="captionText" format="string" />
        <attr name="showIcon" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And this is my `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="id.foodmap.foodmapcustomviews.MainActivity">

    <id.foodmap.foodmapcustomviews.ButtonWithCaption
        android:id="@+id/button_with_caption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:captionText="Test"
        app:iconSrc="@drawable/ic_email_gray_24dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

...but weirdly, Android Studio's preview gave me render error :

> Failed to instantiate one or more classes

with stacktrace :

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at id.foodmap.foodmapcustomviews.ButtonWithCaption.init(ButtonWithCaption.java:54)
>       at id.foodmap.foodmapcustomviews.ButtonWithCaption.(ButtonWithCaption.java:29)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:475)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:262)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:220)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
>       at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:567)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:549)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:863)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:549)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$1(RenderTask.java:680)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My `findViewById()` from `ButtonWithCaption.java` to find `TextView` and `ImageView` also returns null.

Anyone know what caused this? Because it doesn't even show up in the editor preview window.

P.S. If I use , The preview show the element correctly. 
P.S.S. It compiled to my phone with no error, but no `ButtonWithCaption` shown.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your custom view in the xml declared?

Comment: What is line 54 of ButtonWithCaption.java?

Comment: Also, show the code that uses ButtonWithCaption? Are you using it in `activity_main.xml` or some other layout file? Or are you attempting to create a ButtonWithCaption dynamically from Java code?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice line 54: `mImageView.setImageResource(mIconSrc);` yea. i forgot to paste in `activity_main.xml` file. added it just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because you have not inflated the views from `ButtonWithCaption.xml`. One way to fix this is with the static [`View.inflate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#inflate(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) method:

```
 private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ButtonWithCaption, 0, 0);

    try {
        mIconSrc = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ButtonWithCaption_iconSrc, 0);
        mCaptionText = a.getString(R.styleable.ButtonWithCaption_captionText);
        mShowIcon = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ButtonWithCaption_showIcon, mIconSrc != 0);
        mShowText = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ButtonWithCaption_showText, !mCaptionText.isEmpty());

        View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.ButtonWithCaption, this);   // add this line
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bwc_icon);
        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bwc_caption);

        mImageView.setImageResource(mIconSrc);
        mTextView.setText(mCaptionText);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, beautiful. I thought I tried it before? Idk, but this is kinda weird, I think, If this class already called, isn't that means that I already declared it in xml? Why we need to inflate it again then? Doesn't make sense though. (I think, Inflation should happens automatically because I already declared it in xml right?)

Comment: @MosesAprico No, XML layouts are never inflated automatically. Even the layout for an activity must be inflated by calling `setContentView()`.

Comment: well, do you know the reason behind this behavior? Because I think it's just weird. Because, why did I even put something on my XML that I doesn't want to be inflated? Btw, I was a C# and XAML programmer, and elements I put in my XAML (Android Layout XML version of C#), are automatically initialized in my codebehind.

Comment: @MosesAprico When you call View.inflate(), the XML is inflated. The alternative is to create all your views directly in Java which will take a significant amount of code. Personally, I think that using XML is easier and cleaner.

Comment: i meant, when someone declare a View in XML, should it means that "someone" want it to be inflated? I mean, why google designed it not to be auto-inflated? Is there a case that someone wants it otherwise?

Comment: @MosesAprico You are right that Google could have created a mechanism to automatically inflated a layout, for example by requiring the name of the XML file to match the name of the View subclass. Perhaps one reason that Google didn't do this is to allow flexibility in the way views are inflated.

Answer (score -1):

You have to replace the tag  `<RelativeLayout>` with your class, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.yourpackage.app.ButtonWithCaption xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    >
        ...
</com.yourpackage.app.ButtonWithCaption>
```

com.yourpackage.app should be the path where your ButtonWithCaptionclass is.

EDIT:

AYour posted layout sould be your activity layout, the ButtonWithCaptionclass should be your xml element, not your xml name, so change the name, replace the `RelativeLayout` with your custom class and try it.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the RelativeLayout inside the ButtonWithCaption.xml file. This suggestion is incorrect. The <ButtonWithCaption> belongs in activity_main.xml or any other layout file which **uses** ButtonWithCaption. It does not belong in the ButtonWithCaption layout file itself.

Comment: He is trying to inflate a view that is not declaring anywhere. He creates a ButtonWithCaption class extending RelativeLayout, if he does not use that class as a tag inside any layout, he will not be able to use the features he modified. If i'm wrong, please explain yourself again, i didn't get what you mean.

Comment: There are two options: 1. Use `<id.foodmap.foodmapcustomviews.ButtonWithCaption>` in a layout file such as `activity_main.xml` or 2. Create `ButtonWithCaption` instances programmatically in Java code. In neither case, should you use a `<id.foodmap.foodmapcustomviews.ButtonWithCaption>` in in `ButtonWithCaption.xml`. This will cause an infinite recursion when the `ButtionWithCaption` class attempts to inflate the layout.

Comment: There is no difference between what I said and your first option, the xml name has nothing to do with the class name. Of course he should use the posted layout as the activity layout, no matter which name he choose.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I guess you are trying to help, but your are not when you said my answer is wrong, because is not, may be incomplete, but is not wrong.

Comment: The only `<RelativeLayout>` that the OP gave is in `ButtonWithCaption.xml`. Changing this to `<id.foodmap.foodmapcustomviews.ButtonWithCaption>` is incorrect. Instead, `<id.foodmap.foodmapcustomviews.ButtonWithCaption>` should go inside `activity_main.xml` which is not shown in the OP.

Comment: See [Compound Controls](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound) and [Modifying an Existing View Type](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#modifying) in the Android docs for more details.

Comment: Thanks I will check it

Comment: "As Code-Apprentice said, your posted layout sould be your activity layout" This is not what I said. The posted layout is fine as `ButtonWithCaption.xml`. I have posted an answer explaining what the real problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry guys, forgot to add the `activity_main.xml`. Now i've added it.

Comment: Now I get it. But, now I'm asking because I just want to know,  you have a RelativeLayout inside a RelativeLayout, is that needed ? I mean, your custom layout extends RelativeLayout, and inside your xml you declare another Relative.

Comment: @JonathanAste It's not optimal I know, but, I need to center both the icon and the caption inside the "button". I don't think there's any other way to do that. (LinearLayout will strangely trim the `TextView` if it's wider than the `ImageView`)

Comment: @JonathanAste You are right. This is not an optimal solution. Of course, the important thing is to make it work first.

Comment: @MosesAprico if you include the buttonWithCaption.xml layout instead of declare it in your activity xml, and replace the main RelativeLayout for your custom view in your custom  buttonWithCaption.xml  you can avoid using 2 RelativeLayouts, because your custom view is actually a RelativeLayout. I do not want to make things harder, I just want to learn something ;)

Comment: @JonathanAste it's okay, it's always good to have some discussion. So, yeah, as @Code-Apprentice said earlier, to make it work first. Actually, this is just a dummy activity to test my `CustomView` android library. I try to made it to make my codebehind cleaner because I already have a finished one, but without any `CustomView` (just using `<include/>` to `CustomViews`, and not even using `AttributeSet`)

Comment: @JonathanAste AH DUDE! Now I know what were you talking about `RelativeLayout` inside `RelativeLayout`!! I thought you mean the `RelativeLayout` which in the `activity_main.xml`! Many thanks!!